# php file doesn't compile on server

Tags: php

I'm learning to make a registration/login system on remote server and i've ran into this problem where one of the php files doesn't compile on web browser.

here's the code for index.php

```
<html>
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
    Password: <input type='text' name='password'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Log in'><br>
</html>
```

and login.php

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","lowheigh_user","1234") or die("Couldn't connect");
mysql_select_db("lowheigh_phplogin") or die("Couldn't find database");
}
else
die("Please enter a username and a password");
?>
```

When I click submit it doesn't compile and just opens the code in the browser, why is that so?

Is there some significant difference when doing this on remote server compared to local server?

Maybe there's some connectivity problem that I have no idea of and its ruining everything?

Maybe there has to be something instead of "localhost" in

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","lowheigh_user","1234")
```

And please excuse me if this a stupid question, I just want some expert help.

Thanks

Comment: Is PHP and SQL installed on your machine and properly configured?

Comment: I'm not doing this on my own machine, it's on the remote server, which I suppose should have everything configured properly because I pay money for this service.

Comment: You will need to login to your control panel to see what the settings are for your SQL DB. All web hosts send you that information. You may very well have to use `sql.server_xxx.com` as an example instead of `localhost`. Plus, check your logs.

Comment: To check if PHP is in fact running, do a test file `<?php echo "Hello world!";` and/or `<?php phpinfo();` if it stills shows as code or wants to download, then you will need to contact your webhost.

Comment: The first file compiles fine, so I assume PHP is already in there.

Comment: What PHP version is installed?

Comment: Connection details aside, is that the **real** code you're using? If not, please post it here, _verbatim_

Comment: check this screenshot - http://grab.by/xbvy

does it say that PHP is not configured on the server i'm using? then why is it compiling the first code in my original post? just because it has html tags in it?

Comment: `ftp://...` Wait, why are you accessing it over ftp??? should be `http://185.5.53.16/test/info.php`

Comment: thanks much, this was the actual problem.

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`

Answer (score 1):

If you've uploaded a PHP file and the results on the screen is the PHP code as plain text, maybe your web server doesn't have the "PHP module" installed.

Answer (score 0):

Which server are you using? You need to run some server like Apache Httpd with Php module enabled on the server. Best option for you will be to use packaged solutions like WAMP or XAMP which includes all the setup and configurations and eases your pain of configuration.

Comment: `on remote server` OP's not talking about a local environment

Comment: Better solution than wamp/xamp is nginx+phpfpm

Answer (score 0):

Use bitnami WAMP or MAMP stacks to install and setup a preconfigured Apache test environment on your local machine. Will make this a whole lot easier!!

If you are running windows here is the link:

https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp

Comment: `on remote server` OP's not talking about a local environment

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($username&&$password)
```

to

```
if ($username && $password)
```

check it is working